# Using std::bind

Tags: c++, iterator, std, bind

I have to make a function called "GetNextProduct" which returns the "next" product in a multimap of `<int, Product*>` (where the 'int' key is the product reference [number], which is an attribute of the Product object). We are required to use `std::bind` in this function (inside the "find_if").

Here is what I did:

```
Product* ProductManager::getNextProduct(Product* product) const
{

Product* productTemp;

ProductTemp->setReference(product->getReference+1);

FunctorEqual<Product> fonctEqual(productTemp);

auto it = container_.end();
while (it == container_.end())
{
    it = find_if(container_.begin(), container_.end(), fonctEqual);
    productTemp->setReference(productTemp->getReference++);
}

return it->second;
}
```

I think it should work but I don't see where to use bind.

P.S.: if there are typos and stuff, I tried to translate my code manually from French.

Comment: what are you supposed to "bind" ? are you supposed to replace `fonctEqual` with a bound equivalent? perhaps showing us `FunctorEqual` will help

Answer (score 0):

To find next element in multimap i would use following code:

```
Product* ProductManager::getNextProduct(Product* product) const
{
    auto it = container_.find(product->number);
    if (it == container_.end())
        return nullptr; //element not found
    ++it;
    if (it == container_.end())
        return nullptr; //it was the last element in collection. No next element
    return it->second;
}
```

Bind is used to creating wrapper to functions. I don't know what could be bind in this example.